# VBscript "unspecified error" in a script accessing IE - err.number: -2147467259

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I have a problem with a script that I wrote. It works absolutely fine for me and my colleagues in the office (5 different PCs), Win 7 64 and 32 bit.

However, for the people in UK, the script throws an unspecified error as soon as it gets to the line giving an Unspecified Error (I have trapped it and apparently the err.number is  -2147467259)

```
Do while appIE.Busy = True OR appIE.ReadyState <> 4 : Wscript.Sleep(100) : Loop
```

Please note that it manages to open the page, i.e. it goes fine through the

```
set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
appIE.Navigate strSiteAddress
```

If I remove the Do While, the script then fails at

`strCheckIfTMSPage = appIE.document.DocumentElement.InnerHTML`

Can you please advise why it does not work on their machines? They tried IE 10, 9 and 8
the have 32bit Windows and they are using Symantec antivirus, and their security settings are low enough.

Thanks a lot!
Bartosz

Comment: Are you saying it fails at the do while line?

Comment: Well, yes... I think it cannot get the `appIE.Busy`, similarily as it cannot access `appIE.document`

Comment: Try extending the sleep interval to 1000.

Comment: It's not it I'm afraid:(